# MS-Word VBA How to Identify click object

Tags: vba, function, object, ms-word, identify

I have a label object called Lb1. and a sub:

```
Private Sub Lb1_Click()
call function(Lb1)

End Sub
```

But I want to use this function in all other click objects, with a variable as an argument, a variable that should point to the clicked object itself. I dont want to change the argument manually for every click object.
Is there a method in VBA, to identify the clicked object and return the object?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Sub Test(ctl As Control)`

Comment: Use a Control Array?

Comment: As you are using ActiveX controls you have no choice but to change the argument manually for each click event.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Hi TIm ! I am using labels and dropdowns(content control).

Comment: Why are you using ActiveX Controls and Content Controls in the same document? Note, too, that ActiveX Controls are not supported on Macs.